# AWS VPN client on Windows 10: can't add VPN configuration file because of invalid path to the sertificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, client, vpn

I want to add a new profile in AWS VPN client having three files:

- vpn.ovpn
- vpn.companyName.com.crt
- vpn.companyName.com.key
  When I try to add vpn.ovpn I'm getting the error:

"File path: ~/ssh.vpn.companyName.com.crt is in invalid format. It may be a path to a remote server, which is not allowed for security reasons. Only absolute paths are accepted"

Answer (score 3):

For me the **issue** was in the file **vpn.ovpn** the path for both files

1. vpn.companyName.com.crt
2. vpn.companyName.com.key

**were incorect.**

**Solution:**

open **vpn.ovpn** file and scroll to bottom and edit your path to correct location